# Add custom buttons to a message box in Powershell

Tags: powershell, messagebox

**TL;DR**

Is there a way to change the default button options with message boxes in PowerShell?

---

**Full**

Recently, I was playing around with message boxes in PowerShell. So, I used the code below.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to use v1 or v2?", "Version Choice", "YesNo", "Information", "Yes")
Write-Host $result
```

And it works as intended.

[image: Popup]

---

However, I was wondering if there was a way to add a custom option in the buttons to show. Right now, these are the only available button values.

- `AbortRetryIgnore`
- `CancelTryContinue`
- `OK`
- `OKCancel`
- `RetryCancel`
- `YesNo`
- `YesNoCancel`

Can you add a custom button value? Something like...

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to use v1 or v2?", "Version Choice", "V1V2", "Information")
```

Or...

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to use v1 or v2?", "Version Choice", @("V1", "V2"), "Information")
```

However, when I try these, it comes up with an error.

```
Cannot convert argument "button", with value: "V1V2", for "Show" to type "System.Windows.MessageBoxButton": "Cannot convert value "V1V2" to type 
"System.Windows.MessageBoxButton". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name V1V2 to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try 
again
```

A similar error occurs when trying with the arrays.

---

**Conclusion**

In conclusion, is it possible to change the default buttons in the message box?

Comment: I don't think so,  but also is not something hard to do your own popup with windows forms

Comment: I know I can accomplish this with Windows Forms, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this with a message box. If you want though, you can post an answer explaining how to create a similar-like popup with Windows Forms. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` has it's own [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messageboxbutton?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) as you have already explained in your question. So the answer to, "is it possible to use custom buttons" with it, is likely no.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. If you want, you can add an answer, and I'll accept it. It's still good knowing that something isn't available, so I don't have to keep looking for it. Hence, +1!

Comment: You can always create your own wrapper as @Santi suggests, like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/maypk9/uwpstyle_messagebox/). Then, you'd be able to just customize it to your hearts content lol

Comment: Yeah, that's cool. However, I just wanted to simply create a pre-defined message box, while just changing the buttons. Now it's pretty obvious that that isn't possible.

Comment: Just change your sentence : "Would you like to use v1 ?" - YesNo